# How can I change the SID of an Oracle XE instance

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe, sid, service-name

I needed to change the SID of an Oracle XE database (not the Service Name) to match a production database.

When I tried searching online, most of the pages were describing changing or adding a service name through tnsnames.ora; that's not what I needed to do.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [asktom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:963124000346653522) article has the answer, but the formatting and verbosity makes it hard to follow, so here's a summary:

[XE_HOME] means where Oracle XE is installed. Normally this is `C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server`.

Make sure you have Administrator privileges or the procedure will fail.

1. Configure the SPFILE (you can remove the old file if you want)

   1. `copy [XE_HOME]\dbs\spfileXE.ora [XE_HOME]\dbs\spfileNEW_SID_NAME.ora`
   2. `copy [XE_HOME]\database\initXE.ora [XE_HOME]\database\initNEW_SID_NAME.ora`
   3. Edit `[XE_HOME]\database\initNEW_SID_NAME.ora`: It should contain a single line like this: `SPFILE='[XE_HOME]\server\dbs/spfileNEW_SID_NAME.ora'`
2. Shutdown and replace the old service with a new:

   1. `sqlplus / as sysdba` and execute `shutdown`
   2. `lsnrctl stop`
   3. `oradim -new -sid NEW_SID_NAME -startmode auto -pfile [XE_HOME]\database\initNEW_SID_NAME.ora`
   4. `oradim -delete -sid XE`
   5. `lsnrctl start`
3. Update the ORACLE_SID environment property (System Settings > Advanced > Environment)
4. Force Oracle to register with listener

   - `sqlplus / as sysdba` and execute `alter system register;`

You can verify that the SID was changed by executing the following query: `select instance_name from v$instance;`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't like the idea of accepting my own answer. Your answer is much clearer,

Answer (score 3):

I had some problems with the solution posted by Johannes, so I had to do some extra steps.
When trying to connect to oracle (step 4) by doing **sqlplus / as sysdba** I got:

```
ERROR: ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
```

The solution for this was executing the following line:

```
oradim -start -sid NEW_SID_NAME
```

Then connecting with / worked fine, but trying to connect to NEW_SID_NAME with system or HR got me another problem:

```
ERROR: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

I checked that with the query `select instance_name from v$instance;` that the listener would be NEW_SID_NAME, and so did. But running `lsnrctl status` in the command line or querying `select name from dba_services;` didn't show NEW_SID_NAME as a listener.
The solution of this problem was executing the followind sentence on sqlplus:

```
alter system set service_names='NEW_SID_NAME';
```

Maybe you'll need to execute `alter system register;` after this also.

After doing this two steps I can connect to the NEW_SID_NAME with system and HR.

Hope it helps

Comment: Sorry, I forgot, the links that I used to solve this problems where http://mdvreddy.blogspot.com.ar/2011/12/how-to-solve-ora-12560-tnsprotocol.html and https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10201664

Answer (score 1):

In version 11g, all of the previous solution didn't work... I always get the following error when trying to do the  **sqlplus / as sysdba** :

ERROR: ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

Luckily I found a script to do what I wanted to do under [XE_HOME]\config\scripts. The script is named XE.bat and it will instantiate a new database from scratch asking you for the sysPassword along the process. So what I did was :

1. Stop and remove the existing service if any:

> oradim -delete -sid XE

2. Stop the listener
3. Configure the SPFILE as explained by Johannes
4. Make a copy of the script XE.bat, you can name it whatever you want
5. Edit the copy of the script as follows :

   1. Change line "set ORACLE_SID=XE" to "set ORACLE_SID=NEW_SID_NAME"
   2. Change wherever you see "-sid XE" to "-sid NEW_SID_NAME"
   3. Update the line where it calls the "orapwd.exe" command to point to a file called PWDNEW_SID_NAME.ora instead of PWDXE.ora
   4. Update the line that echos the spfileXE.ora into the initXE.ora to echo spfileNEW_SID_NAME.ora into initNEW_SID_NAME.ora (this part may render the step 3 useless but I prefer to do it anyway, just in case...)
6. Execute the script... It will prompt you for the SYSTEM password a few times saying

> Enter value for 1:

or

> Enter value for 2:

That's it, the new database with your NEW_SID_NAME is up and running!!